# Visual Studio Code and ESLint aren't detecting typos e.g. "style.backgroundCOlor". How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

When I'm using Visual Studio Code and the extension "ESLint" my typos are not being recognised. These typos are actually workable (but not working because of the typo) code not just comments. I am new to Visual Studio Code and most of my experience has been with Brackets.

I've tried looking in the ESLint extension files: eslintrc.js, package-lock.json and package.json. I've also looked at my "code-workspace" file but I really don't know what I'm looking for.

document.body.style.backgroundCOlor = "#f00";

The line of code simply won't work because of the obvious upper-case "O". The code obviously works when the "O" is lower-case. It took so long to find this typo because it wasn't being flagged as an error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put `//@ts-check` at the very top of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Olian04, you can put `//@ts-check` at the top of your file, what you can also do is add `"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true` in your `settings.json` file to automatically do this for every file, without having to add this comment at the top of every file and cluttering code (albeit in a very minor way).

To find the `settings.json` file, hit `cmd + ,` and click on the braces in the top right corner.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. I've added what you have said to the top of my "settings.json" file. Under "problems" it says "This setting cannot be applied now. It will be applied when you open this folder directly". How can I fix this?

Comment: The "//@ts-check" works but I'd love it if I could use your method. That would be a lot more convenient.

Comment: You did edit the file that I specified? Not another one? I came across some issues when you only apply these settings only to the current workspace (i.e. your current session).

Comment: The file path from my js file to the "settings.json" is this: "../../.vscode/settings.json". Would this cause any problems? I also only have one ".code-workspace" file. I'm use to using Brackets rather than VS Code so I'm not familiar with using ".code-workspace" files.

Comment: Currently my "settings.json" file looks like this, but the first line is flagged as an error: {
  "javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
}

Comment: Under "Problems" it says: "This setting cannot be applied now. It will be applied when you open this folder directly".

Comment: I don't know, restart/reinstall VSCode, do some google searching, there is something that you're doing wrong, and I can't see your project so I can't help you any further besides giving random suggestions.

Comment: OK. I'll keep hunting. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I've got it to work. Thank you, very much appreciated.